aps-simple-viewer-nodejs, warning “please provide a valid access_token”
Whether I use getInternalToken (which includes Scopes.BucketRead) or getPublicToken (which only includes Scopes.DataRead), the response I always receive is about a 'valid access token' being required.My access_token and screenshot is following。I thought the reason is APS banned my code callback from computer address just now ，and i add 3 address to the white list, but doesn't work too。That's all.
'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlhrUFpfSmhoXzlTYzNZS01oRERBZFBWeFowOF9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6ImFzc2MifQ.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJkYXRhOnJlYWQiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiT2xBTHk3UUFaTHN3VnRFWXF3ak9mTjNtTXFidDhETUEiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2RldmVsb3Blci5hcGkuYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiJLR2NwVllPczF4eXlYb05WRW8zbG5KNFNMMXA1azM0dW5VVWl0cTRuSnJJSXhQSUc3OVRyQ0ZOTzV6b05OVlhWIiwiZXhwIjoxNzI2MTkzODc4fQ.G_BHSRf8TVDv8In1urQuvRXngkb7kM2QnYvWbQTMRCRwqJr39DOk1sr7M7yAOT4G4o1jQSFi9lR4rIN6vv0Oyv7HqSQN1incaLCNh3bhvDZxsvMSd5YeXihIlwSUNlpXb5z_Dwmo-8KNExhkjJj6v3uGB4Hh6RlUFbLASE1mzkpSj3XhbNlvTfxDhixaunVDKjXBDaMCJFLuNQDKlwaMJfwr-9Qo2xxZp1MwYPZA_Nfy9XzNTqpHbwH9G922zTKK_ihlOtd1-v4wb2ny08dtxjRGeKhLq9MrXOu2o5ovvBZVKKg9dl7IjYQW44MjagiV3dQR5pPH_wBwQ4MYBecE_w'

Error image

Error image 2

Setting image

Encode-Decode image

i created an issue in Github Issue
Firstly, i use "@aps_sdk/**" at v0.1.0-beta.1. All was done,dwg|rvt|ifc can be loaded in browser easily. Recently, i find the api response shown some exception. like 403、undefined、translateObject and startJob failure after uploadObject，In short, it seems that the token cannot drive the conversion task anymore
i upgrade aps_sdk version to 1.0.1** and change some code referenced Mr.srivastavarahull, then, the validity of the access_token was appeared.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The token you have provided only has scope data:read, when checked using: https://jwt.io/.  It looks like you have commented line #53 which gets the internal token. In this case line #52 gets the public token which has data:read scope that is not enough for getBucketDetails operation.
You may uncomment line #53 and verify on : https://jwt.io/ that our internal token has bucket:read scope.
